# Fastest way to compare lists with threshold in Julia

Tags: performance, julia

I have to compare 2M+ lists which contains 3136 elements each

The way I do it now is:

```
function compare_matrices(connectivity_list, configuration_list)
    i = 1
    while i <= size(connectivity_list, 1)
        x = connectivity_list[i]
        j = i + 1
        while j <= size(connectivity_list, 1)
            if all(isapprox(x[k], connectivity_list[j][k] ; atol = 0.0001) for k=1:1540)
                    deleteat!(connectivity_list, j)
                    deleteat!(configuration_list, j)
            else
                j += 1
            end
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return configuration_list
end
```

For information, these lists are originally matrices that I vectorised and sorted to be able to compare element per elements. As you can guess, this will take quite a long time.

```
...
push!(connectivity_list, sort(vec(connectivity)))
...
```

Where connectivity is a 2D (lower triangular) matrix

Is there a faster way to compare lists in such way using Julia? I thought about using Sets and compare them but some elements are similar, so it is not possible.

Comment: There are many possible improvements in your code, the most important being to put your code in a function, and avoid global variables. I suggest reading the performance tips section of the manual here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: @DNF Thank you for the link, indeed putting performance important parts in functions improved the timing by around ~ 15%

Comment: @DanGetz It seems to be slower that way

Comment: If you want more advice, I suggest creating a runnable example, with some small input data. I also suspect that this question is more suitable for the Julia Discourse forum (https://discourse.julialang.org/) than for stackoverflow.

Comment: But it runs `isapprox` on all elements, which is suboptimal.

Comment: @DNF I added continue for both loop yes still slower, your last comment speed up things by quite a lot, around 40%, thank you very much

Comment: This seems like a very small speedup, since your original code seems _extremely_ inefficient. I would have expected 10-100x speedup should be easy. Maybe you can update your post with the latest code?

Comment: @DNF updated, I reduced the size of the lists to 1540 by removing all zeroes, which were not useful for the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about 70X faster on some contrived data, so expect a different factor on your real data. The main changes are as follows:

1. Use a `flag` array to keep track of distinct vs. approximately equal vectors to avoid deleting vectors inside the loop.
2. Skip vectors whose `flag` becomes `false`
3. Use `abs(x[k]-y[k]) <= 0.0001` instead of `isapprox`
4. Return the modified array as `configuration_list[flag]`

```
function compare_matrices2(connectivity_list, configuration_list)
    l = length(connectivity_list)
    m = length(connectivity_list[1])
    flag = trues(l)
    for i = 1:l
        flag[i] || continue
        x = connectivity_list[i]
        for j = i+1:l
            flag[j] || continue
            y = connectivity_list[j]
            if all(abs(x[k]-y[k]) <= 0.0001 for k=1:m)
                flag[j] = false 
            end
        end
    end
    return configuration_list[flag]
end
```

Comment: On 45000 lists, it ran for 40 seconds while my script takes 92... quite impressive, I guess I have a lot to learn about Julia still, thank very much.

Comment: @Okano: The 70x speedup that AboAmmar reports seems in line with what I expected. But you are only seeing approximately 2x speedup. I am quite curious about what your data looks like, since the effects of the improvements are so limited.

Comment: Reading the 45000 files takes ~ 35 seconds, which means that the function ran only for ~ 5 seconds, while mine for ~ 60, that's not 70x speedup but it still is quite important, if you compare with my original script (outside functions in global scope) you are probably way over 70x