# Misunderstanding about Julia threading race conditions

Tags: multithreading, julia

This question is a follow up of one of my previous questions: [Fastest way to compare lists with threshold in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74179888/fastest-way-to-compare-lists-with-threshold-in-julia/74188453#74188453)

I am trying to parallelise the code using threads, here is an before/after

```
for i = 1:l
    B[i] || continue
    for j = i + 1:l
        B[j] || continue
        if all(abs(P[i, k] - P[j, k]) <= 0.001 for k=1:1540)
            B[j] = false
        end
    end
end
```

after:

```
for i = 1:l
    B[i] || continue
    Threads.@threads for j = i + 1:l
        B[j] || continue
        if all(abs(P[i, k] - P[j, k]) <= 0.001 for k=1:1540)
            B[j] = false
        end
    end
end
```

Where B is a BitVector of size m and P is matrix of size (m, 1540)

Just threading the loop actually improved performance and seemed to work fine with large array, (shape of P = (400000, 1540)) but doing some tests on smaller arrays with higher number of threads (m = 1056, nthreads > 8) I realised that I wasn't getting the same answer anymore. Some false in B weren't set correctly.

Now what I don't understand is that there shouldn't be a race condition here: no threads will access the same j value?

Changing to the code below actually fix the problem without hurting the performance but I don't really understand why?

```
for i = 1:l
    B[i] || continue
    o = ReentrantLock()
    Threads.@threads for j = i + 1:l
        B[j] || continue
        if all(abs(P[i, k] - P[j, k]) <= 0.001 for k=1:1540)
           Threads.lock(o) do
               B[j] = false
           end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `B` is a BitVector, i.e. 64 booleans are stored in one word. Updating a boolean can interfere with updating another one. Try without the lock (as in the original loop) but with a `fill(true, m)` initialization for `B` (Vector{Bool} uses byte per bool).

Comment: Another benefit to changing from `BitVector` to `Vector{Bool}` is that accessing and/or modifying individual elements in `BitArray`s is quite slow. `BitArray`s are good for saving memory and for batched operations, not for handling individual elements. (I also suggest wrapping your code in functions.)

Comment: @DNF Thank you for your suggestions, this actually fix the problem. Although using fill(true, m) worsen the performance a little bit, not as you expected?

Comment: Currently the method you are using does O(m^2) work. There are ways (see Locality Sensitive Hashing) to reduce this to O(m). If this is a substantial bottleneck in your computation, add more details (how large is `m`, how many trues in final `B`) and it might be possible to probably speed-up quite a bit.

Comment: @Okano If you are going to get reliable benchmarks on this, wrap your code in a function and use BenchmarkTools.jl for timing.

Comment: @DanGetz Thank you for the details, for the largest application m = 100_000_000, the rule seems to be that B only keep around 0.01*len(m) trues (data is very similar). I had a look at LSHFunctions.jl and it seems very interesting, I am not sure how to practically speed up the calculations since the package works with Vectors not Matrices? Should I use the MinHash function?

Comment: You would be hashing the 1540 long sub-vectors of the matrix `P` (use `@view P[i,:]` if needed). Which, to make things faster, should really be generated in a transposed way (i.e. compare `P[k,i]` with `P[k,j]` for all `k`.

Comment: @DanGetz I am not sure if I understand why transposing would make things faster but sure I can try it. So far I successfully reduced the computation time by a factor of 5. The way I do it I still need to perform the O(N^2) search at the end but on a much reduced database, is that what you were thinking about?

Comment: Transposing can have a significant effect because of 2D array's memory layout. Matrices are stored as a series of columns, i.e. P[3,10] is followed by P[4,10]. Keeping the memory locations processed close makes algorithms run faster on modern processors.